# List of matrices

Tags: r, markov-chains

I have a function that defines matrices using a sequence of digits and I want to create a list with the matrices I create using the function. This was my attempt:

```
mc_seq<-function(x){createSequenceMatrix( #Function that creates a matrix using a sequence
  stringchar = x,
  toRowProbs = F,
  sanitize = F,
)
}

for (i in cont_meli){ #cont_meli is a list that contains sequences
    print(mc_seq(i))
}
```

I can see the matrices which I want to calculate but I can't append them to an empty list; when I try to append those matrices into an empty list, each element of the list is the last matrix of the serie.

Comment: `lapply(cont_meli, mc_seq)`

Comment: There's a comma too much in `sanitize = F,
`, the parser will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the list to store matrices before the `for` loop :

```
list_of_matrices <- vector('list', length(cont_meli))

for (i in seq_along(cont_meli)) { 
   list_of_matrices[[i]] <- mc_seq(cont_meli[[i]])
}
```

Or as @Roland and @Rui Barradas mention, `lapply` would work too.

```
list_of_matrices <- lapply(cont_meli, mc_seq)
```